# Laravel forms always direct to response on submission

Tags: php, html, laravel, forms

No matter what method is used, laravel will always direct to the response page and I have no idea why. The correct function is still run, and the correct method is used but there is still a redirect.

Here is a simple delete form for example.

news.blade.php

```
<form action="/news/{{$news_card->id}}" method="POST">
    @method('DELETE')
    @csrf
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>
</form>
```

NewsController.php

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $news = News::findorfail($id);
        $news->delete();
        return;
    }
```

web.php

```
Route::resource('/news', 'NewsController');
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are not returning anything after deleting the record from database.

Comment: Ah ok. I added back() so now it refreshes the page and that kinda solves it so thank you. Is there a way to stop it directing anywhere though, so I can remove it with js without having to refresh the page?

Comment: okay for that you have to use ajax .. submit that delete form using ajax that way you can solve this page refresh issue.